# css.map not found using gulp-ruby-sass

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a file app.scss which is compiled into CSS using gulp-ruby-sass fine, the issue is that in my console I always have this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8100/css/app.css.map 404 (Not Found)
```

I dont **actually** care too much about seeing the pre-processed file when I inspect in the browser (I find the rendered CSS better to spot mistakes in). What I would like is for this error message to go away.

I am using Gulp to build the app, and for the purpose of this question, it means files are moved from one folder to another to be served.

I tried creating one with

```
sass css/app.scss:css/somethingelse.css --sourcemap
```

But it just resulted in:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing --sourcemap without a value is deprecated.
Sourcemaps are now generated by default, so this flag has no effect.
```

At the bottom of my rendered CSS I have this comment:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=app.css.map */
```

My build file contains the following:

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  gulp.src([appDir + '/www/css/*.css', './commons/styles/main.scss', appDir + '/www/css/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plugins.rubySass({style: 'expanded'}))
    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer('last 1 version'))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir + '/www/css'));
});
```

I have also tried adding sourcemap: 'none' to the rubySass constructor.

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Why are you piping `.css` files to `rubySass` ? You should give `.scss`

Comment: The full line of code was updated, I just stripped out some to make it easier to read. The scss and css are concatenated into one file.

Comment: You should concat the `.css` with the `.scss` after they are converted, but tha'ts another problem. You also not have a `dest` in you task, is that for test purposes only ? Try to add `.pipe(gulp.dest('test.css'))` and tell if the map is still here

Comment: I have updated the whole code block to what appears in mine

Comment: Since you concat everything that is in the `css` folder and you're copying the output of your task in the same folder, the old `app.css` file with the `sourcemap` comment will still be there. Delete it and relaunch your task, it should be good

Comment: When you say 'delete it' what do you mean? at the point before comiling there is no comment pointing to a map, its only during this process, I have css and scss files I want to combine...

Comment: I mean the resulting `app.css`

Comment: I have deleted the app.css in the /dist folder (which is where they end up) and rebuilt with no changes to the build.js and the issue is still there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62105/discussion-between-apercu-and-ben-taliadoros).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is something wrong with gulp-ruby-sass.
Instead of using

```
sourcemap: none
```

use

```
"sourcemap=none": true
```

to disable sourcemaps

I tried it myself to fix an ["Unknown Word" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979433/gulp-with-gulp-ruby-sass-error-style-css-map31-unknown-word/26979768).

[Source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/156)

Comment: amazing! what a weird bug

Comment: They should make it `{ '!!sourcemap===\'none\'': true }` if they want to make it even more wierd...