# gulp with gulp-ruby-sass: Error: ../style.css.map:3:1: Unknown word

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, sass, gulp

Getting a strange error using a basic gulp/express build watch.

**Directory Layout**

```
 project/
   - sass/
      - style.scss
   - gulpfile.js
   - index.html
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    sass         = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss    = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename       = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('express', function() {
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')({port: 4002}));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname));
  app.listen(4000);
});

var tinylr;
gulp.task('livereload', function() {
  tinylr = require('tiny-lr')();
  tinylr.listen(4002);
});

function notifyLiveReload(event) {
  var fileName = require('path').relative(__dirname, event.path);

  tinylr.changed({
    body: {
      files: [fileName]
    }
  });
}

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', sourcemap: false }))
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('sass/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('*.html', notifyLiveReload);
  gulp.watch('css/*.css', notifyLiveReload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'express', 'livereload', 'watch'], function() {

});
```

**Style.scss**

```
body { position: relative; }
```

The express server/livereload works fine, but when it tries to compile the stylesheet I'm getting this error (even with `sourcemap: false`)

```
gulp-ruby-sass: write style.css.map

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: <LOCAL_PATH_HERE>/style.css.map:3:1: Unknown word
```

Comment: It's pretty clearly telling you that there's something wrong on style.css.map, line 3, char 1.  Have you checked your mapfile?

Comment: Map file does not exist. It's creating that in tmp, and previously it was autocreated without errors. i'm suspecting [this update](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass#sourcemappath) to sass is relevant but haven't found solution.

Comment: Removing the pipe to `gulp-autoprefixer` allows it to build successfully. hmm.

Comment: getting the same error (without express)

Comment: Does the answer I provided below not resolve it for you?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Disabling sourcemaps is some kind of mystery right now. You have to do it like this

```
.pipe(sass({ "sourcemap=none": true }))
```

[Source](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass/issues/156)

Comment: Not the best solution (I'd actually want to use source maps), but better than mine, and the best I've seen! Great find

Comment: Agreed. As soon as I find a solution (or the bug gets fixed) and we can use sourcemaps without the `Unknown word` error I'll let you know.

Answer (score 5):

Not entirely sure *why* this fixes it, but changing the autoprefixer pipe to:

```
.pipe(autoprefixer({
     browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
     cascade: false
}))
```

and putting it before the sass pipe (top) allows it to build succesfully.

Comment: that fixed it indeed. No idea why. Is it "save" to use autoprefixer before sass? Doesn't seem right to me

Comment: Ok it is indeed a bad idea. Comments marked with `//` aren't striped by sass before going into autoprefixer, which causes even more errors... I need to find the real issue here

Comment: Taking your answer, moving it to top, then using autoprefixer works! Nice find!

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem keeping the source maps and using [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-filter):

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter')
var filterCSS = filter('**/*.css');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', sourcemap: true }))

      // Filters only css files before auto prefixing
      .pipe(filterCSS)
      .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1'))
      .pipe(filterCSS.restore())

      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
      .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

Comment: Pretty neat workaround to the autoprefixer crapping out on the mapfile issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with the **gulp-ruby-sass plugin**. I found **[this](http://www.devworkflows.com/posts/getting-scss-auto-prefixer-and-source-map-to-play-nice/)** blog post which explains that there are a couple of bugs in the gulp-ruby-sass plugin regarding source maps. They have both been closed a little over a week ago. If you upgrade to **gulp-ruby-sass~1.0.0-alpha** this should fix the issues your having with source maps.

If that doesn't work the article I linked to above shows how to use the **gulp-sass** plugin which which doesn't have the source map issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to gulp-ruby-sass 1.0.0-alpha. It uses gulp-sourcemaps and should avoid all iterations of this problem.

Comment: sadly it doesn't really as autoprefixer doesn't work with `gulp-ruby-sass 1.0.x` at all.

Comment: If it doesn't please submit an issue. It certainly should.