# Gulp ruby-sass and autoprefixer do not get along

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, autoprefixer

I have a `styles` task in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
  var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
    return gulp.src('app/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass({sourcemap: true, sourcemapPath: '../scss'}))
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log(err.message); })
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'));
});
```

which generates this in the console:

```
[14:25:21] Starting 'styles'...
[14:25:21] gulp-ruby-sass: stderr: DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing --sourcemap without a value is    deprecated.
Sourcemaps are now generated by default, so this flag has no effect.
[14:25:21] gulp-ruby-sass: directory
[14:25:25] gulp-ruby-sass: write main.css
  write main.css.map

  events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
  Error: /Users/stevelombardi/Documents/command-central/ccgulp/main.css.map:3:3: Unknown word
```

IF I comment out the pipe to autoprefixer, no errors, everything compiles. What's the deal here?

Note, I also cannot seem to disable the writing of a sourcemap. I tried all the other settings from the repo page for grunt-ruby-sass and none work.

I can live without autoprefixer, but would love to get it working...

Comment: Are the *sass* files compiled correctly without errors?

Comment: they are, if AP is commented out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979433/gulp-with-gulp-ruby-sass-error-style-css-map31-unknown-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
```

Try this:

```
browsers: ['last 2 version'],
```

If that doesn't work, I've had better luck with gulp-sass and gulp-sourcemaps.

```
// Compile Sass & create sourcemap
.pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
.pipe(sourcemaps.write())
.pipe(gulp.dest('css'))

// Autoprefix, load existing sourcemap, create updated sourcemap
.pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version')
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue seems to happen related to the **main.css.map**, even if you didn't want one, using `gulp-ruby-sass@0.7.1` at the time I am writing this.

I've come across two different solutions so far:

### 1) If you *don't* need sourcemaps:

```js
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('app/styles/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            "sourcemap=none": true // hack to allow auto-prefixer to work
        }))
        .pipe(prefix("last 2 versions"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

This is what I have used as I recently encountered this issue.

### 2) If you *do* need sourcemaps:

Then you should try `gulp-ruby-sass@1.0.0-alpha`

([relevent github issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/20))